# Building dynamic table with handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I am trying to create a dynamic table with handlebars.js.
An example of an object I want to put in the table is:

```
Object { title: "The Room", director: "Tommy Wiseau", genre: "Drama?", rating: "1"}
```

The HTML I would like to look like:

```
    <thead>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Director</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>Rating</th>
    <th>Edited</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>The Room</td>
      <td>Tommy Wiseau</td>
      <td>Drama?</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2017-05-16</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

My problem is that the user can also add their own table headers, so i can't for example just do:

```
<td>{{title}}</td>
```

It has to be done dynamically. I have looked at: `{{#each}}`, but just can't seem to wrap my head around around it. Also, how can I print the property name instead of just the value in an object (like I want in the table headers).

```
  <thead>
    {{#each data}}
    <th>{{@key}}</th><!--property name here-->
    {{/each}}
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each data}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{this}}</td><!--property value here-->
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
```

This is my template. I feel like I am closing in on the right solution, but I am not sure where I am doing something wrong.

```
$.getJSON("php/loadItems.php?category=" + selected, function(data) {
    let source = $("#itemTemplate").html();
    let template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    delete data[0].id
    $("#tableContainer").append(template(data));
  });
```

This is how I handle the data in my JS. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

Based on what you are describing, I think you would have no option other than to build an array of table headers (object keys) by iterating over *every* object in your array and filtering out all of the duplicates. In other words, you must build an array of all of the *unique* keys from all of your data objects and these will serve as the column headings in your table. You could use an existing library to help yo do this, like [Underscore's `.uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq), but I will provide an example implementation:

```
var uniqueKeys = data.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
    return acc.concat(Object.keys(obj).filter(key => acc.indexOf(key) === -1));
}, []);
```

Next, we must pass our array of unique keys to our template. The unique keys will be used to create the table headings as well as in [lookup](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) operations for each object in `data`.

```
template({
    uniqueKeys: uniqueKeys,
    data: data
});
```

Our template must be updated to the following:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        {{#each uniqueKeys}}
            <th>{{this}}</th>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {{#each data}}
        <tr>
            {{#each ../uniqueKeys}}
                <td>{{lookup .. this}}</td>
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
     {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Note that the line `{{lookup .. this}}` is saying, "render the value on the current object in `data` at the property with the name of this key in `uniqueKeys`.

Also note that I added `<tr>` tags within your `<thead>`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead), these are the only permissible tags within a `<thead>`.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/9bwhzwky/) for reference.

Comment: Tremendous help! Thank you. Btw you can also get an array of object keys using `Object.assign(summaryObj, obj)` to accumulate keys from each `obj` in `summaryObj`, and then `Object. keys(summaryObj)` gives the array of keys.

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work for what you're trying to accomplish?

```js
{
  "titles": [
    "The Room",
    "Test"
  ],
  "tableObjs": [{
      "director": "Tommy Wiseau",
      "genre": "Drama?",
      "rating": "1"
    },
    {
      "director": "Tommy Wiseau",
      "genre": "Drama?",
      "rating": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
<thead>
  {{#each titles}}
  <th>{{@key}}</th>
  <!--property name here-->
  {{/each}}
</thead>
<tbody>
  {{#each tableObjs}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{this.director}}</td>
    <td>{{this.genre}}</td>
    <td>{{this.rating}}</td>
    <!--property value here-->
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. Since the user can add stuff themselves I would not be able to know what the property names are. In this instance they might add another category; say "Notes" where they could write what they want. I would have no idea what the property name would be then