# Postman Visualisation and iterating with Handlebars

Tags: json, templates, iteration, postman, handlebars.js

I'm running Postman, and I want to use the Visualisation tool to convert the JSON response into a set of tables. Essentially the response contains an array of objects in its 'content' property. I want to iterate over that array, and for each object, produce a table of property name, value rows.

Assuming I have a result something like this:

```json
{
    "content": [
        {
            "Study Number": "X123",
            "Primary Completion Date Planned": "2018-11-09",
            "Primary Completion Date Actual": null,
            "Favourite Colours": [
                "Blue"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "last": true,
    "totalElements": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "first": true,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true,
        "empty": true
    },
    "size": 100,
    "number": 0,
    "numberOfElements": 1,
    "empty": false
}
```

I can iterate over it to get a workable result like this, for JUST THE FIRST ELEMENT of content:

```js
var template = `<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
            <th>Prop</th>
            <th>Val</th>
        </tr>
        {{#each response}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{key}}</td>
                <td>{{val}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>`;

const response = pm.response.json();
data = { 'response' : [] };

for (var prop in response.content[0]){
  if (response.content[0].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
    data['response'].push({ 'key' : prop, 'val' : response.content[0][prop] });
  }
}

// Set visualizer
pm.visualizer.set(template, data);
```

How would I iterate over multiple elements in 'content'? I've tried iterating using '#this' within the each loop, but I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: Is this post helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44095020/3397771 ?

Comment: Hmmm... not sure. The thing is, I don't know the property names or property counts beforehand. And, sadly, reading further, that's the objection of the O.P.

Comment: I don't understand why you are building the `data.response` array to send to the template. Could you just send `pm.response` directly to your template and leave the looping (iteration) to the template?

Comment: If you could show me how to do that I would be grateful. :-)

Comment: My two issues - not knowing the property names in advance, and iterating over an array of objects. The JS solves item 1, because I clearly only want to see local properties, and by casting them into 'prop' and 'val' I can build a template. I can't see how to build dynamic templates in Handlebars :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much faffing, here's the working code:

```js
var template = `
{{#each content}}
    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
            <th>Property</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        {{#each this}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{@key}}</td>
            <td>{{.}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
{{/each}}`;

const response = pm.response.json();

// Set visualizer
pm.visualizer.set(template, response);
```